# Invoke-webrequest insert CR in uri parameters making the request failed

Tags: powershell, invoke-webrequest

I'm trying to download a file using invoke-webrequest (or invoke-restmethod).

This works perfectly in interactive mode:

```
$Ack = $Msg.ackId
$BucketID = $Msg.message.attributes.bucketId
$FullName = $Msg.message.attributes.ObjectId
$MsgName = ($Msg.message.attributes.ObjectId -split "/", 5)[4] # split the name
$ObjectID = [uri]::EscapeDataString($FullName) # convert " " in %20 and / in %2F
$uribucket = "https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/{0}/o/{1}?alt=media" -f $BucketID, $ObjectID

Invoke-WebRequest -uri $uribucket -Headers $Header -OutFile $WrkDir\$MsgName -Verbose

GET https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/bucket_name/o/blabla/REGIE/L216/WRK/myfile.docx?alt=media with 0-byte payload
```

But ran in service mode the request fails.
It looks like a CR is inserted in the uri (in the /L216/ directory >> /L2CR16/)

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/bucket_name/o/blabla/REGIE/L2
16/WRK/myfile.docx?alt=media with 0-byte payload
StatusCode: NotFound
ErrorMessage: Not Found
```

Using curl.exe works perfectly (interactive or service mode) but I'd like to use native Powershell Commands

Comment: There appears to be some code missing from your question - how are you constructing `$uribucket`?

Comment: What is in `$FullName` or in `$Msg` ??? Works fine for me: `[uri]::EscapeDataString('alt=media with 0-byte payload')` --> `alt%3Dmedia%20with%200-byte%20payload`

Comment: Hi Mathias
Sorry. I edited my post. 
I confirm the $uribucket parameter is properly set.

Comment: Hi Iron
upper in the script, I get a collection of $messages

Then I've got a foreach loop
foreach ($Msg in $messages.receivedMessages) {

Comment: Please try to create a [mcve]